# Azure function not able to reference file

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I created a function which uses a package that needs a file reference in order to work.

So the folder structure looks like this (forgive me for the poor visualization)

```
-ConnectorFolder
 |-ConfigFolder
   |-connectorconfig.properties
 |-ServiceFolder
   |-Service.cs
-Function.cs
```

in the Service.ts folder I run this piece of code:

```cs
public static SessionManager CreateSession()
{
ConfigFactory.setConfigLocation("ConnectorFolder/ConfigFolder/connectorconfig.properties");
}
```

On my local device I set Copy to outputdirectory to Copy Always and this code runs just fine.
However when I run it on Azure I get the following error

> connector.exception.Exeption: Invalid url to location ]ConnectorFolder/ConfigFolder/connectorconfig.properties[

This is an internal error from the package but it makes me believe the file cannot be resolved?

Does azure require a different way to reference file paths or am I missing something?

Comment: `.properties` extension file is for Java language and its equivalent is `.settings` extension file in C# project. Please define your config properties/code in `.settings` file and check.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT That would not work as the connector package uses a Java ikvm so it needs the java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when I run it on Azure I get the following error
> connector.exception.Exeption: Invalid url to location ]ConnectorFolder/ConfigFolder/connectorconfig.properties[

Make sure your files were in the root directory i.e., `D:\home\site\wwwroot` where the Azure Function Project resides exactly.

Please refer [here](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-access-azure-functions-wwwroot-folder/) for more detailed information.